# Using external mongodb with meteor development

Tags: mongodb

A Meteor server code uses Accounts-ui package gets started like this:

```
appDir$ MONGO_URL=mongodb://username:password@cloud-host-url meteor
```

After creating the account, the user document fails to show up in the mongodb on the cloud-host but shows up in the local mongodb copy.
How can I correctly use the cloud mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you set your `MONGO_URL`, try this in your CLI:

`export MONGO_URL=mongodb://username:password@mongo_link && meteor`

Comment: I tried that for no avail. The Accounts-ui still created the user in the local mongodb and not the mongodb on the cloud as referenced to in the export EnvVar.

Comment: Could you try create another collection and insert some documents to see where they are created? localhost db or cloud db

Comment: the newly created collection is found in the local db and not the cloud db.

Comment: hmm? check you mongo url, is it in this format: `mongodb://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER>:<PORT>/<DB>`

Comment: yes, it is the exact copy from the settings.json MONGO_URL EV. at the end of it after the <DB> there is `?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin`

Comment: hmm? I doubt that your code overrides the MONGO_URL value to localhost db somehow. To test that let edit the `MONGO_URL` value to a random value: `export MONGO_URL=whatever && meteor`, if your code really uses that value you should see an error in server log.

Comment: That is true, it gives errors with `export MONGO_URL=whatever && meteor`

Comment: The value in the <server>:<port>/<db> references instance on the cloud. Is it possible that since it might take few seconds to respond that the the command returns before the cloud service has the chance to respond and thus fall back onto the local mongodb?

Comment: That should not be the case, as far as I know Meteor does not fallback to local db if it fails to connect external db specified in MONGO_URL, it just throws error if error occur. You should check your code carefully to make sure the MONGO_URL value is right. Try log the value of MONGO_URL when your app starts on server: `Meteor.startup(() => console.log(process.env.MONGO_UR))`