# Use external MongoDB and fetch data with Meteor.js

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to develop a Meteor app using external MongoDB, but I'm not sure how to connect and fetch external Mongo data using Meteor.

The following is what I've tried.

---

### Fetch external MongoDB data in the shell (success)

I can connect into external MongoDB under Terminal (use database `sm_app`):

```
$ mongo <USER>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER>:<PORT>/sm_app
```

and fetch the only one data:

```
> db.servertop10.findOne()
```

It shows:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("......")
  "list": [
    ...
  ] 
}
```

---

### Fetch external MongoDB data in Meteor (failed)

Now I try running Meteor with external MongoDB on my Mac:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER>:<PORT>/sm_app meteor run
```

then try to fetch data in Meteor.js:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const ServerMonitor = new Mongo.Collection('servertop10');
console.log('findOne:', ServerMonitor.findOne());
```

but it shows:

```
findOne: undefined
```

---

### Questions

1. How can I fetch the data under Meteor.js?
2. Is it possible using other databases in Meteor.js with the same external MongoDB? How to do this?

---

### Edit

Previously, I only tried fetch data on the front end. Now I try logging the results on both server side and client side.

```
// Import this file on the main.js files of both server and client
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const ServerMonitor = new Mongo.Collection('servertop10');
Meteor.startup(() => {
  console.log('MONGO_URL:', process.env.MONGO_URL);
  console.log('findOne:', ServerMonitor.findOne());
}
```

The server side shows:

```
> MONGO_URL: mongodb://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER>:<PORT>/sm_app
> findOne: {
  "_id": ObjectId("......")
  "list": [
    ...
  ] 
}
```

but the client side shows:

```
> MONGO_URL: undefined
> findOne: undefined
```

I still failed to fetch the data in the `render()` of a React component:

```
render() {
  // still print `undefined`
  console.log('findOne:', ServerMonitor.findOne());
  return (<h1>Hello</h1>);
}
```

but I can fetch the data on the console of the browser (with `autopublish`):

```
> ServerMonitor.findOne()
  Object {_id: ..., ...}
```

I don't know why I can't fetch the data on the client side.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40713857/2845061

Comment: `Meteor.startup(() => console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)) ` prints `undefined`

Comment: Make sure you use export if you are on Mac or Linux

Comment: I tried to print the `process.env.MONGO_URL` on the server side and fetch the data, and it worked well. When I tried to fetch data on the client side using the same collection code, I got nothing. I have no idea about this. Please see the new edit on the post.

Comment: It takes some time for server to send data to client. You see `undefined` on client console because at that time server has not finished sending data yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Khang and Mikkel, I finally resolve this problem.

If you encounter the same problem, please check:

- Use `export` for external Mongo with URL (`MONGO_URL`).
- If you use React with Meteor, make sure use `createContainer` from `react-meteor-data` to trigger the callback when the database is up or its data changes.

After using `export` for `MONGO_URL`, I find that I still can't fetch data in client side, but it works in the server side.

This is because I use **React** with Meteor, I forgot to use `createContainer` derived from `react-meteor-data` to connect the data changes from mini-Mongo collections to React components. Logging fetch results in React's `render()` or `Meteor.startup()` will print `undefined` until the callback passed to `createContainer` was triggered by database changes.

Answer (score 0):

check with

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://<USER>:<PASSWORD>@<SERVER>:<PORT>/sm_app" meteor
```

Also if you are not using package autopublish and insecure then you will have to use publish and subscribe methods.

Comment: Please see my new edit. I can now fetch data on server side, but not on client side with autopublish.

Comment: If the data can be fetched on server side you can create a method call from client side to get the data from server side. [link]https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html